# Apache disable SSLv2 SSLv3

Tags: ssl, apache-httpd

I know that there are some Questions around here that comes along with this Topic.
But I really don't know what I can do anymore.

So here's the point:

- I am using Apache 2.2.22 on OpenSuse 12.3.
- The SSLProtocol option is in my ssl.conf
- I have tried out all of this options:

  ```
  SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
  ----------
  SSLProtocol +TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  ----------
  SSLProtocol TLSv1
  ----------
  SSLProtocol -ALL TLSv1
  ----------
  ```

But what ever I try, still all Protocol are available...

Why can't I  disable it?

Edit:
So i have tried so much out that i want to recap it:
I only have one declaration of SSLProtocol and it doesn't matter where I put it (in my vhost conf or my ssl-default conf).
I know that it is loaded, because the denying of all protocols with the option "-all" works fine. The denying of a special protocol doesn't work (like the option -SSLv3). If one protocol is allowed, every protocol is available (for example with "SSLProtocol TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3" or "SSLProtocol -all TLSv1" every protocol is available!).
Some ideas?

Comment: Have you reloaded/restarted apache after each config stage? Enabled debugging? What do the logs tell you?

Comment: I have restarted apache every time and I don't know what the logs should say? For me it looks normal but i will set the log level to debug and check again Edit: still the same with log level debug...

Comment: How do you know they are available? If you try connecting with "openssl s_client -ssl3 -host [your ip] -port 443" You will get "routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number if its not supported. If it's supported you will see a certificate and much more.

Comment: I checked it with "opensll s_client..." and I checked it with ssllabs.com

Comment: Do you have more than one ssl.conf on your server? Are there separate SSL entries for vhosts?

Comment: Have you tried with "-ALL" in lower case? In http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html the syntax is in lower case for SSLProtocol and upper case for SSLCipherSuite.

Comment: No there is only 1 ssl.conf and there i tried the lover case '-all'. Still no change

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this myself with the POODLE exploit.

For OpenSuSE only, add the following into your `/etc/apache2/ssl-global.conf`

```
<IfDefine SSL>
<IfDefine !NOSSL>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  #Your other stuff
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

Save, exit, and restart apache with the following `rcapache2 restart`

If there are still any problems let me know.

Comment: I have already tried that...

Comment: @manderda, What tool are you using to check that SSLv3 is still present?

Comment: as I said before: I am checking my Server with SSLLabs.com and with "openssl s_client -connect website:443 -quiet -ssl2"

Comment: @manderda what is in the respective vhosts and in httpd.conf? Your original question explicitly mentions `ssl.conf` while the default for OpenSuSE is to use `ssl-global.conf`

Comment: I do mean the ssl-global.conf. Sorry for that misstake

Comment: @manderda I agree with @xx4h and see if appending the SSL to the bottom of your `vhost.conf` file and try that.

Comment: I tried that... still no change. If i don't declare any protocol or deactivate all with "-all" I get an error when I start the Apache (which shows, that the option takes effect). But when I declare any protocol (E.G. "SSLProtocol SSLv2" all protocols are available. It doesn't matter if I deactivate them with "-SSLv3 or TLSv1". How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `SSLProtocol ...` gets loaded after your **SSL site**.

You can check if this is the case with:

`strace httpd -t 2>&1 | egrep 'open\("\/etc\/(apache(2|)|httpd)\/.*\.conf'`

don't know how opensuse implements apache2, maybe use `apache2 -t` instead of `httpd -t`.

If your **SSL conf** is below your **SITE conf** or or the config which contains your **SITE definition**, the config does not apply to your **SITE conf**.

You have two options then:

1. make sure **SSL conf** is loaded before your **SITE conf**.
2. implement `SSLProtocol ...` in your **SITE conf**/**SITE definition**.

Comment: With Site conf you mean where my VirtualHost is defined? I dont have a site.conf file...

Comment: Yep. Take **SITE conf** and **SITE definition** as synonyms here

Comment: okay, my ssl conf is loaded before my site conf. SSLv2 and SSLv3 still available.

Comment: Maybe it's overwritten globally by another conf file (inside a VirtualHost only applies to the VirtualHost itself). `grep -Ri SSLProtocol /etc/httpd` (or maybe /etc/apache2).

Comment: I have searched the /etc/apache2/ folder with 'grep -nR "SSLProtocol" .' and the only time it gets called is in my ssl.conf.

Comment: Just append `SSLProtocol ...` to the VirtualHost and check if that works.

Comment: I have already tried that. I'm pretty sure that the SSLProtocol is loaded from the ssl-gloabl.conf file. Because if I do "SSLProtocol -all" I'll get an Error when I restart the apache cause no SSLProtocol is given

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
```

Instead of

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
----------
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
----------
SSLProtocol TLSv1
----------
SSLProtocol -ALL TLSv1
```